# A GPU-based N^2 comparison

Tags: c++, concurrency, opencl, gpgpu

From a newbie on GPU programming I resort to you for advice, be aware that I am not really interested in a particular hw solution, so NVidia/ATI is ok, although probably OpenCL would be better. But everything is kosher!

So, I have 2 series of 64-bits integer pairs, let's say `list(<top, bottom>)`, and I need to compare each element from the list with every other element. Yes, a simple `N^2` algorithm. In details, I need to see if, given `l1` and `l2` from the list, `l1.top == l2.bottom`. If so, store the matching elements, otherwise, discard them.

Nothing more.

Obviously this won't scale even in a multithreaded approach when reaching millions of elements in the list.

I learned about Cuda, and tried few programs, but every program modified something. There was no example on something like a concurrent vector or list, which I am using right now to store the matching pairs.

Can you point me in the right direction about porting this to the GPU?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create two copies of the list, sort one by top and one by bottom. Then use parallel binary search to match first copy tops with second copy bottoms. Finally use a gather operation to gather the matching pairs.

Gather, binary search, and sort, can be found in the thrust gpu library.

See here: https://github.com/thrust/thrust